# StringBuilder backed up by a linked list

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I notice that `StringBuilder` is backed up by an array, which makes it allocate a single memory block. I don't like that behavior because the memory is highly fragmented and somtimes it's hard to find a big enough block of memory, which triggers the GC...

I wonder if there is a version of `StringBuilder` backed up by a linked list, which would be more memory-friendly.

Comment: This screams "premature optimization."  (Also, I suspect that memory fragmentation, while common in languages with manual memory allocation, isn't nearly as common a thing in GC'd languages.)

Comment: My profiler says different. It triggers a GC just to allocate 600k of memory. I can't afford a GC at certain times.

Answer (score 3):

First of all I'd seriously question the need for an alternative: for *most* use-cases the implementation of `StringBuilder` is perfectly sensible and works just fine. Measure before you decide.

If you indeed need similar objects of such enormous size that this becomes a problem, then something like [Ropes for Java](http://ahmadsoft.org/ropes/) might help: It's effectively a library of many different `CharacterSequence` implementations (with a common interface [`Rope`](http://ahmadsoft.org/ropes/doc/org/ahmadsoft/ropes/Rope.html)) optimized for different interactions.